# Receive RabbitMQ from remote exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

I have two nodes, NodeA and NodeB.

NodeA has

```
a) RabbitMQ running 
b) an application 'foo' listening on a 'topic' and bound to a 'Q1'.
```

Node B

```
a) no RabbitMQ 
b) an application 'bar' that sends a RabbitMQ message using the NodeA's IP address.
```

So a push from 'bar' to 'foo' works. Now can 'foo' push to 'bar'? Meaning, can a message be sent to a remote node that doesn't have a RabbitMQ instance running?

Clustering, Federation, Shovel all needs a RabbitMQ instance running on the all nodes. Wondering if there is any existing way to achieve this?

Thanks

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now can 'foo' pull from 'bar'?

yes - "foo" creates a connection to Node A and consumes from a queue, just like any other consumer.

RabbitMQ is a broker model where there is typically one central server or cluster that all message producers and consumers use.

You don't need an instance of rabbitmq per app.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say push. Edited the Q.

Comment: I agree with Derrick. The normal use case is like Derick said one rabbitmq-machine (or one cluster if the rates are high enough) for many publishers and subscribers. The clustering, federation, shovel each solve a different user case... the documentation for each is very high quality and good... I reckoned you start reading each plugin's documentation to see where each is appropriate.

Comment: @iobelix - push vs pull makes no difference in the architecture of the RMQ system. you have code that connects to the RMQ server. it can push, pull, do both at the same time or one at a time.